# Ubuntu 18.04.3 /var/log/syslog Error message lircd flooding

Tags: syslog

I checked /var/log/syslog on Ubuntu 18.04.3 and discovered that it is flooded with a repetition of errors, but primarily the main one is shown below. Written every second.

```
lircd[1298]: lircd-0.10.0[1298]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/input[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
lircd-0.10.0[1298]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/input[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
```

Is this normal? Or should I resolve this? If so how do I go about resolving the LIRC?

I was able to find out more about using google. A first since google list novice answers first and usually doesn't work with advance issues that I have been having. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=860551  This has to due with debian defaulted to assume that there is an IR Device installed and when one isn't LIRC.d keeps trying anyway.

Looking for a more flexible solution.  One that will allow me to turn on when I need it.  Like an extension.  Off to researching more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read in a link that its probably a bug, some people uninstall it with
    sudo apt-get remove lirc and stop the flood of this error.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lirc/+bug/1768291

Comment: I varied that sudo apt-get remove lirc did stop the spam to syslog.  I was coming back to log that I did that since that seems to be the easiest option for my setup and needs. Thanks.